# How can I store calculated time into database using mysqli data type time?

Tags: php, laravel, mysqli, time

I am trying to store calculated time into database using mysqli data type time. Calculated means I am trying to store play time or the time user spent to play game. So I have column `spent_time` which data type is `time` and I set default value `00:00:00`.

When I try to store 5 minutes and 30 seconds `00:05:30` the query returns following error

```
SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect time value: '' for column 'time_spent' at row 1
```

and following is the script which is inserting record using query

```
 $Log   = new Log;
 $Log->user_id       = request()->user()->id;
 $Log->time_spent    = $time;
 $Log->save();
```

Can someone kindly guide me how can I fix this error, I would appreciate. Thanks

Comment: You'll need to show some code on how you insert this value. Clearly the value you attempt to insert is empty.

Comment: As per your edit, we have *absolutely no idea* what `$time` is. Check the value of that variable. This should be your first debugging step. ;-)

Comment: @Qirel this is the value `00:15:07` of `$time`

Comment: it seems the $time variable is getting overwritten with some null/empty string value somewhere, show the full code from the controller method?

Comment: Then you likely have something odd going on in your `Log` class, which should be the *second* thing you check. I really can't be guessing to what's wrong, you need to do some basic debugging and show all the relevant parts of the code, otherwise we can't help you.

Comment: ` $Log->time_spent    = '00:15:07'; $Log->save() ;` does this persist data in the table?

Comment: Please can you show the code in your `Log` model.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a type of field to store the `time` which isn't right. The time field allows you to store a time (like 8am, 2pm and 9pm) but not accumulated time (like 1 second, 3 minutes or 5 hours).

If you want to save the time to the database, either change the way you are registering how long a user is online (possibly in seconds, use an `int` field for that) or store the value you have as a `varchar` in the database.